# Creating unique sessions $_SESSION's

Tags: php, session

So I'm just testing out sessions and seeing how they work. With the code below I would have thought that I would get three distinct results, how ever after I have run it several times the last two entries are the same. Some how the values from the generic session are being added to the second session. The first appears to be unaffected.

What is going on here? Can some one else's generic session add values to my own? Is there a way to stop this from happening?

The session_unset() is there just for clearing after a test.

Code:

```
<?php 
    session_id('site');
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['someVal']="yup";
    var_dump($_SESSION);
    // session_unset();
    session_write_close();

    session_id('another');
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['anotherVal']='Another';
    var_dump($_SESSION);
    // session_unset();
    session_write_close();

    session_start();
    $_SESSION['newVal']='newVal';
    var_dump($_SESSION);
    // session_unset();
    session_write_close();
?>
```

Output:

```
array (size=1)
  'someVal' => string 'yup' (length=3)
array (size=2)
  'anotherVal' => string 'Another' (length=7)
  'newVal' => string 'newVal' (length=6)
array (size=2)
  'anotherVal' => string 'Another' (length=7)
  'newVal' => string 'newVal' (length=6)
```

Comment: why would you want one request to have 3 sessions? That doesn't even make sense.

Comment: I noticed you don't have a session_id for the third one but I think @developerwjk 's comment is perhaps more relevant.

Comment: After `session_id('another');` that is the session ID for the following 2 `session_start` calls.

Comment: For starters, it's technically only two different sessions because the third code block doesn't set a new `session_id()` .. I also wonder if this is the not the first time the session has been accessed. If a persistent session with the id of 'another' is being accessed again a second time, `newVal` would have been added to the session from the previous request.

Comment: There's a reason that session_id's are set by PHP to be unique.. so there aren't session collisions like your code here.

Comment: This is just testing, I don't have this in my code but if you load your site and then mine this could happen. 

So even with generating a unique session ID this can still happen, can't it? If you load my site and I set an id and then load your site without an id it will use mine. So can it be cleared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first please note that session ID may be not what you think it is. If you set the same session ID for two different users, they will share all session data, when normally you want to have different session ID for each user.

Then it's because last two cases share common session ID. When you use the `session_id()` function the session ID is set permanently either up to the end of the script or untill next `session_id()` call.

`$_SESSION` variable is populated on each `session_start()` so in details you have:

1. Here you're opening a session with `'site'` ID. `var_dump` will always output an array with `'someVal'` set.

   ```
   session_id('site');
   session_start();

   $_SESSION['someVal']="yup";
   var_dump($_SESSION);
   // session_unset();
   session_write_close();
   ```
2. Here you're opening session with `'another'` ID. For the very first request, `var_dump` will output only `'anotherVal'`.

   ```
   session_id('another');
   session_start();
   $_SESSION['anotherVal']='Another';
   var_dump($_SESSION);
   // session_unset();
   session_write_close();
   ```
3. Finally you're opening `'another'` session again. `$_SESION` for ID `'another'` has now both `'anotherVal'` and `'newVal'` set and this will sustain in all following request (untill session data is there, not deleted by garbage collector), also when `'another'` session is started in 2nd case.

   ```
   session_start();
   $_SESSION['newVal']='newVal';
   var_dump($_SESSION);
   // session_unset();
   session_write_close();
   ```

Comment: I think I'm still leaning toward this not being the first request (which is how we would interpret the output without knowing otherwise).

Comment: Yep, you're right. I've updated my answer for better explanation.

Comment: Great explanation. I see why it is doing it but if another site doesn't set an id  I could end up with their data in my session. Or maybe I'm missing something very simple here?

Comment: Actually you can, if you share your environment with that another site. But even shared hosting providers usually isolate client's data, so you don't have to worry. Google for session collisions for more info.